# It is true that $ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = L $?

Tags: limits

$$ \lim_{x \to a} f(x) = L \Leftrightarrow \lim_{x \to a^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^-} f(x) = L    $$

Do you think it is true? I need to know that to determine these two limits:

$ \lim_{x \to 0} x^{|\tan x|} \overset{??}{=} 1 $

$ \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{(\sin x - \tanh x)^2}{(e^x-1-\ln(1+x))^3} \overset{??}{=} \frac{1}{36} $

It is clear that it is fulfilled when $ x \to 0^+ $, but what about when $ x \to 0^- $?

Thank you all!

Comment: Yes, the limit is equal to $L$ if and only if the left- and right-hand limits equal $L$.

Comment: The leftsided limit of the first expression surely does not exist.

Comment: Okk!! Any formal reason why the leftsided limit of the first expression can't exist? @SeverinSchraven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**hint**

For the first, you can only compute $\lim_{x\to 0^+}$ using

$$(\forall x>0)\; x^{|\tan(x)|}=e^{\frac{\sin(x)}{x\cos(x)}x\ln(x)}$$
and the well-known limits.

For the second, you will need Taylor expansion
$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}(1+\epsilon_1(x))$$
$$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}(1+\epsilon_2(x))$$
$$\sin(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{6}(1+\epsilon_3(x))$$
and

$$\tanh(x)=x-\frac{x^3}{3}(1+\epsilon_4(x))$$

Comment: Yeah ty! I knew how to solve it, but the problem was that my homework was about found the limit and there were no limit so I was very confused haha

Comment: @ToniRiveraVargas If the function is not defined at$ ]x_0-\eta,x_0[$, you cannot speak about the  limit at the left of $ x_0$.

Comment: I disagree that the the function is not defined for a whole open interval. Surely we can make sense if we have rational exponents. That is enough to speak of a leftsided limit.

Comment: We can for example consider the sequence $x_n=\arctan(-1/(2n+1))$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}_{>0}$. Then $$x_n^{\vert \tan(x_n)\vert}=(\arctan(-1/(2n+1)))^{1/(2n+1)}<0.$$